# Residence/Work Permit for Company Without Germany Subsidiary?

Tags: working-visas, us-citizens, residency, foreign-employment, contracts

My employer wishes to send me to Berlin for approximately two years in order to complete a project and later establish a presence in the German-Speaking market.

They do not, however, wish to create a branch or subsidiary immediately.

Does anyone have experience with applying for a residency/work permit where the contract is with an American employer (provided it is reviewed by a German attorney in order to ensure it is compliant with German employment law) that does not have an established branch in Germany?

This project is essentially something I have been tasked entirely with (I asked for it) so it is up to me to figure out how they shall send me.